# In what scenario will this event be null?

Tags: c#, events, mvp

I'm building an application using the MVP pattern. In order to make things happen in the presenter I'm creating events in the view, and the presenter will watch for them. ReSharper is giving me warnings about a possilble null reference exception, and I see tutorials that check for null before triggering the events. In what way exactly can the events be null? Below is an example of my code:

```
public partial class PrinterSelectView : Form, IPrinterSelectView
{
    public PrinterSelectView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event Action Canceled;
    public event Action Saved;

    private void btnCancelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Canceled != null)
        {
            Canceled();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'd love to know why someone thinks it's unclear what I'm asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If no code registers for the event (calls `Canceled += <some code>`) then the event will be null. The check ensures there's any registered listeners before triggering the event.

Comment: So it's not the view itself that makes that event valid, but the presenter when it binds the event to a method to use. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

They are always null by default. The caller of this object may subscribe to the events later, for example:

```
var view = new PrinterSelectView();
view.Canceled += OnCanceled; // now it's not null
```

But before, or if the caller never subscribes your event will be null.

One generic way to prevent this kind of a warning is to just always assign an empty delegate to it yourself, such as:

```
public partial class PrinterSelectView : Form, IPrinterSelectView
{
    public event Action Canceled = () => { }; // will never be null now
    public event Action Saved = () => { };
    // ...
}
```

This just assigns an empty lambda expression to both events and this allows you to just assume that the events will never be null.

Comment: A good workaround, but in my case I think I would prefer to catch and log a when an event fails because nobody is listening.